# jQuery $(element).each function doesn't work on newly added elements

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I am using .each function to iterate trough list of elements. I am having initial list of matched elements and .each works great on these. But I can add new elements via AJAX method... .each don't work on this newly added elements?

I know about live events and rebinding of events for newly added elements, but .each is not event I could not find any help on how to use this correctly to affect newly added elements.

How to solve this?

`//Uploadify callback where I add new items
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data)
{
    $(".blank").remove();
    $("#lib-contentWrap").append(response); 
}
});`

//And my each loop where I loop the elements. All elements are 
wrapped inside the #lib-contentWrap div. And the looping begins 
if I change the state of a checkbox (=checkbox check/uncheck)!
$('#chk-selected').change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(".lib-item").each(function () {
            if ( $(this).hasClass('item-selected') ) $(this).slideDown('fast');
        }); 
    }
    else {
        $(".lib-item").each(function () {
            if ( $(this).hasClass('item-selected') ) $(this).slideUp('fast');
        }); 
    }
});

Thanks,
Primoz

Comment: Can you please post your code, including the ajax method which updates your page?

Comment: @Karim: added code in my original post!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the `.each()` loops through the matched elements when it was run...the new elements weren't there to do things to when you called it.  Solution: call it again, but only for the new elements when you add them.  You need to call the same `.each()` on your ajax result, with the context of the result to restrict the each to it.

For example if you have this currently:

```
$(".myDiv").each(function() {
 //stuff here
});
```

You need to call the same selector and same code in your success (or complete, whatever you're using) ajax function like this:

```
success: function(resp) {
  $(".myDiv", resp).each(function() { //each, but only on the new guys
   //stuff here (same as before)
  });
  //Do more stuff with your response...
}
```

The key here is the `, resp` bit, it tells jQuery to select the same elements you were before, but **only inside the context in the second parameter**, in this case: your ajax response containing the new elements that need love.

### Update based on new question code

First, you can shorten your code here *(optional not required)*:

```
$('#chk-selected').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".lib-item.item-selected").slideDown('fast');
    }
    else {
        $(".lib-item.item-selected").slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

In the callback, trigger the that same handler to run again *(this won't change the selection, just trigger the handler to run)*:

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data)
{
    $(".blank").remove();
    $("#lib-contentWrap").append(response); 
    $('#chk-selected', response).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work... And duplicating code doesn't sound a nice practice at all as it increases the chance of bugs and needs more support.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate code. You can assign a name to the function and use it in both places.

Comment: Yes sure that's correct, but anyway the solution didn't work for me... I've copied my .each code in my onComplete function, where I add new elements, but the each still worked only on original elements.

Comment: @Primoz Rome - Updated the answer for your specific posted code, let me know if it gives you any problems.

Comment: @Nick: I think it should be `.lib-item.item-selected` - with no space in between - you're checking whether `.lib-item` hasClass `.item-selected`

Comment: I cannot find the response callback in today's [post-1.8 jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). How should one use your approach with these newer version of jQuery? An update may be beneificial.