# Newly added elements $.each and events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’ve read many posts already on the [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and newly added **elements + event attachment**. Many of the current Questions regarding this topic on StackOverflow don’t seem to work for me. [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is normally recommended since it allows us to append new elements and **still maintain a single event listener + handler**.

In my current code:

1.`$(‘input[type="checkbox"]’).on(“change”, function(e){});`

2. //I do a logical if-statement, `if(this.checked) else`
3. //With-in the `if`-statement I run `$.each`, however, once I have appended new element in this context a new `li` to the `ul`, it stops working.

*Out of the curiosity has anyone encountered something like this before, and if YES, how have you folks solved this?*

Some **StackOverflow** posts I have already seen:

[jQuery $(element).each function doesn't work on newly added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352644/jquery-element-each-function-doesnt-work-on-newly-added-elements)

[jquery: dynamically appending li items to ul then adding click, but click runs through each li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361123/jquery-dynamically-appending-li-items-to-ul-then-adding-click-but-click-runs-t)

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$(document).on(“change”, ‘input[type="checkbox"]’, function(e){ /////});` Also It would be great if you show the code.

Comment: Why should I attach it to a document? Isn't that global? Of course the most outer of nods on the HTML layout.

Comment: Then use closest static parent

Comment: Satpal, can you post that as an answer? Your first comment.

Comment: You have to attach it to the document or a static parent of the appended element. It is called as delegation.

Comment: Satpal, please post your first comment above as an answer. The one with the code-snippet of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating elements.**

You need to use  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

*Example*

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
  //Your code
});
```